# How to add value from another class (java)

Tags: java

I have two classes: profesor and subject

```
public class Profesor {

private int numbClassroom;


public Profesor(int numbClassroom) {
    this.numbClassroom = numbClassroom;
}


public int getNumbClassroom() {
    return numbClassroom;
}

public void setNumbClassroom(int numbClassroom) {
    this.numbClassroom = numbClassroom;
}

public String ToString(){
    return "Number of classroom: "+numbClassroom;
} }
```

The second class is:

```
public class Subject{
String name;
Profesor lecturer = new Profesor();
Date yearOfStudy;


public void Dodeli(Profesor p){
 ??????
}}
```

**I do not know how to add professor like a lecturer to a current subject**

Comment: what would Dodeli(Profesor p) do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? I don't see any problem.

```
public void Dodeli(Profesor p){
   lecturer = p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Profesor lecturer = new Profesor();
```

No need to instantiate lecturer. Just declare it. Then have getter/setter methods for it

Then you can assign Professor to Subject

```
Subject subj = new Subject("OOP");  //assuming you have corresponding constructor
subj.setLecturer(new Professor());  //or if you have existing prof object
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe require something like this : try to encapsulate your code

```
public class Professor {


    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 }


    public class Subject{

    private String name;
    private Professor professor;
    private int numbClassroom;
    private Date yearOfStudy;

    public int getNumbClassroom() {
        return numbClassroom;
    }

    public void setNumbClassroom(int numbClassroom) {
        this.numbClassroom = numbClassroom;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Professor getProfesor() {
        return professor;
    }

    public void setProfesor(Professor profesor) {
        this.professor = profesor;
    }
    public void Dodeli(){
        System.out.println("Pofessor  "+getProfesor().getName()+" is teaching "+getName()+" in Room NO :"+getNumbClassroom());

    }
}

public class TestImpl {
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        Professor professor = new Professor();
        subject.setName("Biology");
        professor.setName("MR.X");
        subject.setNumbClassroom(1111);
        subject.setProfesor(professor);
        subject.Dodeli();



    }
}
```